# Make a service check to see if it's already scheduled or running in JavaFx

Tags: java, service, javafx, bluetooth, javafx-8

I'm writing a Bluetooth messaging program as part of a JavaFX 8 desktop app. I'm using the Service class from javafx.concurrent to write and read messages so my UI thread isn't swamped with work. My code is as follows:

```
public MessageHandler(String url){
    this.url = url;
    try {
        StreamConnection streamConnection=(StreamConnection)Connector.open(url);

        OutputStream outStream=streamConnection.openOutputStream();
        outData = new DataOutputStream(outStream);

        InputStream inStream=streamConnection.openInputStream();
        inData = new DataInputStream(inStream);

        writer = new Writer();
        reader = new Reader();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void write(String message){

    writer.setMessage(message);
    writer.start();
}

public String read(){
    reader.start();
    return reader.getValue();
}

class Reader extends Service<String>{

    @Override
    protected Task<String> createTask() {

        return new Task<String>(){

            @Override
            protected String call() throws Exception {

                return inData.readUTF();
            }

        };
    }

}

class Writer extends Service<Void>{
    String message;
    public final void setMessage(String message){this.message = message;}
    public final String getThisMessage(){
        return this.message;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        final String _message = getThisMessage();
        return new Task<Void>(){

            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                outData.writeUTF(_message);
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
}
```

Originally I had planned to have each call of read() or write() form a new instance of the service, but decided against this because I can't have multiple reads or writes happening concurrently. This is why I made 'reader' and 'writer' into instance variables. The code in my main class looks like this.

```
MessageHandler mssgHandler = new MessageHandler(connectDevice.get());
mssgHandler.write("@");
mssgHandler.write("abfjsd");
System.out.println(mssgHandler.read());
mssgHandler.write("!");
```

When I run my program with this code I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can only start a Service in the READY state. Was in state SCHEDULED
```

which makes sense. I need a way for the service to check if it's already scheduled or running before it runs again, and to wait it it's not ready. This must work across both services as well, i.e. Reader should check if Writer is doing something and vice versa. I know the isRunning() method exists but as far as I'm aware it doesn't check if it's scheduled, which is what I'm having problems with right now.

Thanks for your help!

Solved:

I added a queue and changed the code so it starts the next write/read only on the success of the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`getState()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#getState--) on your `Service`, which will return you the [`current state of the Worker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.State.html).